# Solutions to the functional equations $f(sx) = tx$ and $f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose that $s,t \in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ with $t \ne s$. Does there exist a continuous bijection $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ which simultaneously satisfies the functional equations
$$
f(sx) = tx
$$
and
$$
f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)
$$
for all $x \in [0,1]$?

---

It is fairly straightforward to show that such a function has to satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Moreover, $f(s^n) = t^n$ and $ f(1-s^n) = 1-t^n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This makes it seem like the existance of such a function $f$ is not possible, but I cannot yet disprove it.

Comment: If $f(1)=1$, then it's pretty obvious from the first statement that $f(1) = f(sx) \implies 1 = \frac{t}{s}$, so it would make $t=s$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You can't put $x = \frac{1}{s}$ into any of the equations, since we require $x \in [0, 1]$ and $s < 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(0)=0$ implies that

$$f(1-s) = 1-t$$

Since $s\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$, we have that $\frac{1-s}{s}\in(0,1)$ so

$$1-t = f(1-s) = f\left(s\cdot\left(\frac{1-s}{s}\right)\right) = t\cdot\left(\frac{1-s}{s}\right)$$

$$\implies s=t$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(sx) = tx
\implies 
f(x) = tx/s
$.

$f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)
\implies
t(sx + (1-s))/s = t(tx/s) + (1-t)
$
or
$tx+t(1-s)/s
=t^2x/s+1-t
$
or
$x(t^2/s-t)
=t(1-s)/s-(1-t)
=t/s-t+t-1
=t/s-1
$
or
$xt(t/s-1)
=t/s-1
$
so that
$t=s
$
and
$f(x) = x$.

Note that no initial values
of $f(x)$
or restrictions on $s$ and $t$
 are needed.