# Solutions to the functional equations $f(sx) = tf(x)$ and $f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: functional-equations

Suppose that $s,t \in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ with $t \ne s$. Does there exists a continuous bijection $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ which simultaneously satisfies the functional equations
$$
f(sx) = tf(x)
$$
and
$$
f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)
$$

---

I strongly beleive such a function cannot exist.

Such a function $f$ must satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Moreover, it must also satisfy $f(s^n) = t^n$ and $f(1-s^n) = 1-t^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using this, I can show that for some specific values of $t$ and $s$ such an $f$ cannot exist. For example, if $t=0.9$ and $s = 0.8$ then plotting $(s^n,t^n)$ and $(1-s^n,1-t^n)$ yields the following plot:

[image: t=0.9 s = 0.8]

Any $f$ satsifying the functional equations would have a graph which goes through each point of the plot. Since $f$ must be stricly increasing we have a contradiction. On the other hand, if $t=0.6$ and $s = 0.55$ then the corresponding plot is given by:

[image: t=0.6 s=0.55]

Here there is no clear obstruction to injectivity.

---

Edit: At the suggestion of mathworker21, plotting more points in the "graph" of $f$ for $t=0.6$ and $s = 0.55$ yeilds the following plot:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com]

Again such and $f$ cannot be injective, but it is not clear how to turn this into a proof.

---

Note: I previously made a post [Solutions to the functional equations $f(sx) = tx$ and $f(sx + (1-s)) = tf(x) + (1-t)$ on $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365041/134117)
where the question I asked in the body contained a typo. Since I already awarded the correct answer for the incorrect question, I thought I should make a new post to not take away from the answers that were contributed.

Comment: If it was just a typo, why did you say: "That's what I was looking for, thanks! I think I fell down a rabbit hole of overthinking it..."

Comment: I hadn't parsed the fact that i'd made the typo at that point, and it didn't stick out immediately in their proof either until I wrote it down again later.

Comment: can you compute $f(s^k(1-s^n))$ or stuff like that? maybe computing enough of those will give an obstruction to injectivity for any initial $s,t$.

Comment: So if you have any polynomial p such that $f(p(s)) = p(t)$, then $f(sp(s)) = tp(t)$ and $f(sp(x) + 1 - s) = tp(t) + 1 -t$, starting with $p = 1$ and $p=0$ you can build a whole family of polynomials satisfying $f(p(s)) = p(t)$ . Using this I'm pretty sure I have a way to show that the set of values $\{ p(s) \mid p \text{ built in this way } \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. I still can't seem to work it into a proper contradiction though.

Comment: well, if you try plotting a bunch of stuff for $t=0.6$ and $s=0.55$ do you now get an obstruction to injectivity?

Comment: I've added a graph with more points, and it's clearly not injective (or even a function for that matter). I'm still not sure how to rangle it into a proof for general $s$ and $t$. You can even show that the "graph" must be the attractor of a certain iterated function system on $\mathbb{R^2}$, but this still doesn't seem to help.

Comment: good. so do you think there's no *function* $f$ satisfying both functional equations, let alone a continuous bijection? anyways, is there any algorithm for finding polynomials in the 'whole family' you built that will give an 'injectivity' contradiction (or a 'function' contradiction)? For example, what if you alternate between $sp(s)$ and $sp(s)+1-s$?

Comment: I doubt that there is even a function, but I'm happy with any type of contradiction (no injectivity, no continuity, no function, or otherwise).  I don't think the process of just alternating between the two types of operations on polynomials works in general. I think the choice of sequence of operations ($sp(s)$ or $sp(s)+1-s$) to run into a contradiction depends heavily on both $s$ and $t$.

Comment: It is easy to prove the following: (1) $f(y+1-s) = f(y)+1-t$ for all $y \in [0,s]$. (2) $f(x+\frac{1}{s}-1) = f(x)+\frac{1}{t}-1$ for each $x \in [0,2-\frac{1}{s}]$. These two identities give a stronger version of injectivity in certain regions -- they say how much $f$ must jump up by. They should be useful.

Comment: So I derived your identites, and noted they both hold for $x \in [0,2 - \frac{1}{s}]$. I can also show that $f(x+1-s) - f(x + \frac{1}{s} - 1) = - \frac{(1-t)^2}{t} < 0$ in this region, but im not sure what you mean about a stronger version of injectivity.

Comment: What I meant was that it is easier to contradict than injectivity. You can ignore that comment if you want. Anyways, you can just look at your plot and see if $f$ can't jump by how much it needs to.

Comment: any progress? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So I've spent some time playing with the two expressions involving $f$, and I assume that you are aluding to the fact that you can find an $x$ value for which $f(x)$ takes on two distinct values depending on the expression used. I'm unsure of how to get to this though, am I missing something?

Comment: let's say we know $f$ is increasing and $f(x+.3)-f(x) = .1$. If you know $f(0) = 0$ and $f(.4) = .09$, then you get a contradiction.

Comment: Well I've spent a couple of hours going down many rabbit holes with your previous comment, and I'm still not there. I figured that .3 is either $1-s$ or $\frac{1}{s} - 1$, and that $f(.4)=0.09$ should come from which ever equation wasn't used to get $f(x+.3) - f(x) = .1$. However, I couldn't get much further than that. Presently, I'm trying to show that there exists $x \in [0,2-\frac{1}{s}]$ such that $x  + (1-s) > \frac{1}{s}-1$ and $f(x) + (1-t) < \frac{1}{t}-1$.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to create any confusion. I saw you had a plot of many points. you were trying to see whether the plot could possibly be consistent with an increasing function. What I am saying is that it needs to be consistent with an increasing function and with the equations $f(y+1-s)=f(y)+1-t$ and $f(x+\frac{1}{s}-1)=f(x)+\frac{1}{t}-1$ (or whatever other equations you've found). That's all. And just to be clear, I don't know how to solve your problem; I am just giving my thoughts.

Comment: And to clarify my previous comment, $.3$ is either $1-s$ or $\frac{1}{s}-1$. You could have gotten $f(.4)$ from a variety of places, not necessarily the other of the two equations mentioned in my 5th comment. Like I've said, you're always able to generate a plot of points. I understand you have to handle (theoretically) arbitrary $s$ and $t$, but maybe it shouldn't be too hard to contradiction increasing and those two equations (or whatever other equations you've found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous bijection from $\left[0, 1\right]$ to $\left[0, 1\right]$ such that for $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$ holds
\begin{align}
f\!\left(sx\right) &= tf\!\left(x\right) \label{constr 1} \tag{1} \\
f\!\left(sx + 1 - s\right) &= tf\!\left(x\right) + 1 - t \label{constr 2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
for some fixed pair $\left(s, t\right) \in \left(2^{-1}, 1\right)^{2}$, $s \neq t$. If such function exists, then it's inverse $f^{-1}:\left[0, 1\right] \rightarrow \left[0, 1\right]$ is continuous bijection, which satisfies
\begin{align}
f^{-1}\!\left(tx\right) &= sf^{-1}\!\left(x\right) \\
f^{-1}\!\left(tx + 1 - t\right) &= sf^{-1}\!\left(x\right) + 1 - s
\end{align}
That's why without loss of generality we asume that $s > t$. I will work with modified equation \eqref{constr 2}, where substitution $x \rightarrow 1 - x$ is used
\begin{equation}
f\!\left(1 - sx\right) = tf\!\left(1 - x\right) + 1 - t \label{constr 2'} \tag{2'}
\end{equation}
Set of finite strictly increasing sequence $\left(n_k\right)$ of numbers $n_{k} \in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{0\right\}$, $0 \leqslant k \leqslant l$ we denote as $\mathfrak{S}_{l}$. For $\left(n_{k}\right) = \mathfrak{s} \in \mathfrak{S}_{l}$
and $x \in \left(0, 1\right)$ we define next series
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\mathfrak{s}\right) = \sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{l} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}}
\end{equation}
When sequence $\left(n_k\right)$ is infinite and fixed, but also strictly increasing, we will denote as $\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right)$ for partial sums of series
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}\!\left(x\right) = \sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}}
\end{equation}
Note that $\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right)$ and $\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\mathfrak{s}\right)$ lies in $\left[0, 1\right]$ and $\mathcal{S}\!\left(x\right)$ always finite as series absolutely converges
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} x^{n_{k}} \leqslant \sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} x^{k} = \dfrac{1}{1 - x}
\end{equation}

> ### Lemma 1
>
> For any $x \in \left[2^{-1}, 1\right)$ function $\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\cdot\right)$ dense in $\left(0, 1\right)$. Moreover if $y \in \left(0, 1\right) 
>  \backslash \, \mathbb{E}\Big(\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\cdot\right)\!\Big)$ then we can find strictly increasing sequence $\left(n_k\right)_{k \,\geqslant\, 0}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> y = \mathcal{S}\!\left(x\right) = \lim\limits_{l \,\rightarrow\, \infty} \mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) = \sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}}
> \end{equation}
>   $\mathbb{E}$ stands for the image of the function.

Let $y \in \left(0, 1\right) \backslash \, \mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\cdot\right)\right)$. We construct sequence $\left(n_k\right)$ inductively with next properties:
\begin{align}
& (-1)^{l}\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) &&> y \label{S one} \tag{3} \\
& (-1)^{l}\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) - x^{n_{l}} + x^{n_{l} + 1} &&< y \label{S two} \tag{4}
\end{align}
Sequence of points $\left(x^{n}\right)$, $n \geqslant 0$ represents a "point" partition of an  $\left(0, 1\right)$. Under "point" partition $\mathbf{P}$ of $\left(0, 1\right)$ I mean sequence of points, such that set of intervals $\left(a_i, a_{i + 1}\right)$ $\left(\text{or } \left(a_{i + 1}, a_{i}\right)\right)$ creates a partition of $\left(0, 1\right) \backslash\, \mathbf{P}$.

So there exists unique $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{0\right\}$ such
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_{0}\!\left(x\right) - x^{n_{0}} + x^{n_{0} + 1} &< y < \mathcal{S}_{0}\!\left(x\right) \\
x^{n_{0}+1} &< y < x^{n_{0}}
\end{align}
and base of induction is proved. To prove induction step $(l \rightarrow l + 1)$ we use that $x \geqslant 1 - x$:
\begin{align}
(-1)^{l}\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) - x^{n_{l} + 1} &= (-1)^{l}\sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{l - 1} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}} + x^{n_{l}}\left(1 - x\right) \\
&\leqslant (-1)^{l}\sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{l - 1} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}} + x^{n_{l} + 1} \\
&= (-1)^{l}\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) - x^{n_{l}} + x^{n_{l} + 1} \\
&< y 
\end{align}

Last inequalities shows that set of all $n > n_{l}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
(-1)^{l}\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right) - x^{n_{l} + 1} < y 
\end{equation}
is not empty. Combining this with \eqref{S one} and with monotonicity of $x^{n}$ we conclude that there unique $n_{l + 1}$ such \eqref{S one}, \eqref{S two} holds true for $l+1$.
Taking limit in \eqref{S one} of an even/odd subsequences, we get that $\mathcal{S}\!\left(x\right) = y$.

Partial sums $\mathcal{S}_{l}\!\left(x\right)$ are elements of $\mathbb{E}\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\cdot\right)\right)$, which means that $\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\cdot\right)$ dense in $\left(0, 1\right)$.

We can restate one part of **Lemma 1** as follows

> ### Lemma 1'
>
> for any $y \in \left[0, 1\right]$ and $x \in \left(2^{-1}, 1\right)$ there is strictly increasing sequence $\left(n_{k}\right)$ such
>   \begin{equation} 
> y = \sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}x^{n_{k}} \label{repr} \tag{5}
> \end{equation}
>   where last sum understood in the sense of $\mathcal{E}$, when $\left(n_{k}\right)$ is finite, and in the sense of $\mathcal{S}$ otherwise.

From \eqref{constr 1} and \eqref{constr 2'} it's provable via induction that for natural $n$ and $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$
\begin{align}
f\!\left(s^{n}x\right) &= t^{n}f\!\left(x\right) \label{pow 1} \tag{6} \\
f\!\left(1 - s^{n}x\right) &= t^{n}f\!\left(1 - x\right) + 1 - t^{n} \label{pow 2} \tag{7}
\end{align}

> ### Claim 1
>
> for any $l,p \geqslant 0$, $\left(n_{k}\right) = \mathfrak{s} \in \mathfrak{S}_{2l}$ and $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$ we have
>   \begin{equation}
> f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) - s^{n_{2l} + p}x\right) = \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) - t^{n_{2l} + p}\Big(1 - f\!\left(1 - x\right)\!\Big)
> \end{equation}
>   When $\left(n_{k}\right) = \mathfrak{s} \in \mathfrak{S}_{2l + 1}$ then
>   \begin{equation}
> f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) + s^{n_{2l + 1} + p}x\right) = \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) + t^{n_{2l + 1} + p}f\!\left(x\right)\!
> \end{equation}

We will prove this claim by induction on $l$. Base of induction follows from next sequence of transformations
\begin{align}
f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) - s^{n_{0} + p}x\right) &= \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) - t^{n_{0} + p}\Big(1 - f\!\left(1 - x\right)\!\Big) \\
f\!\left(s^{n_{0}} - s^{n_{0} + p}x\right) &= t^{n_{0}} - t^{n_{0} + p}\Big(1 - f\!\left(1 - x\right)\!\Big) \\
f\!\left(1 - s^{p}x\right) &= 1 - t^{p}\Big(1 - f\!\left(1 - x\right)\!\Big)
\end{align}
 Let us prove case $2l \rightarrow 2l + 1$. For $\left(n_{k}\right) = \mathfrak{s}' \in \mathfrak{S}_{2l + 1}$ we organize $n_{0}, \dots, n_{2l}$ in new sequence $\mathfrak{s}$. Thus
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\mathfrak{s}'\right) = \mathcal{E}\!\left(x;\mathfrak{s}\right) - x^{n_{2l + 1}}
\end{equation}

Take $p = n_{2l + 1} - n_{2l}$ and $x \rightarrow 1 - s^{p'}x$, $p' \geqslant 0$
\begin{align}
f\Big(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) - s^{n_{2l + 1}}\left(1 - s^{p'}x\right)\!\Big) &= f\Big(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) - s^{n_{2l + 1}} + s^{n_{2l + 1} + p'}x\!\Big) \\
&= f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}'\right) + s^{n_{2l + 1} + p'}x\right) \\
&= \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) - t^{n_{2l + 1}}\Big(1 - f\!\left(s^{p'}x\right)\!\Big) \\
&= \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}'\right) + t^{n_{2l + 1} + p'}f\!\left(x\right)\!
\end{align}
For case $2l + 1 \rightarrow 2l + 2$ we do the same. With properly selected parameters we have
\begin{align}
f\Big(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) + s^{n_{2l + 2}}\left(1 - s^{p'}x\right)\!\Big) &= f\Big(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right) + s^{n_{2l + 2}} - s^{n_{2l + 2} + p'}x\!\Big) \\
&= f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}'\right) - s^{n_{2l + 2} + p'}x\right) \\
&= \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) + t^{n_{2l + 2}}f\!\left(1 - s^{p'}x\right)\! \\
&= \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}'\right) - t^{n_{2l + 1} + p'}\Big(1 - f\!\left(1 - x\right)\!\Big)
\end{align}
As consequence we get that for any $l \geqslant 0$ and $\mathfrak{s} \in \mathfrak{S}_{l}$
\begin{equation}
f\!\left(\mathcal{E}\!\left(s;\mathfrak{s}\right)\right) = \mathcal{E}\!\left(t;\mathfrak{s}\right) \label{f fin} \tag{8}
\end{equation}
In addition, with **Lemma 1** and continuity of $f$ we conclude that for any strictly increasing sequence $\left(n_k\right)$ holds true
\begin{equation}
f\!\left(\sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}s^{n_{k}}\right) = \sum\limits_{k \,=\, 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}t^{n_{k}} \label{f inf} \tag{9}
\end{equation}
As we can see from \eqref{f fin}, \eqref{f inf}, it doesn’t matter to us that the sequence $\left(n_{k}\right)$ is finite or infinite. Therefore, we will not pay attention to this and will simply write the index $k$ at the bottom of the sums of type like in  \eqref{repr}.

> ### Claim 2
>
> For $x \in \left[0, 1\right]$
>   \begin{equation} f\!\left(1 - x\right) + f\!\left(x\right) = 1 \end{equation}

Claim enough to prove for $x \in \left[0, 2^{-1}\right]$.
From **Lemma 1** we know, that it possible for $x \in \left[0, 2^{-1}\right]$ to construct $\left(n_{k}\right)$ such that $n_{0} \geqslant 1$ $\left(\text{as } s^{1} > 2^{-1}\right)$ and
\begin{equation}
x = \sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}s^{n_{k}}
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
f\!\left(1 - x\right) + f\!\left(x\right) &= f\!\left(1 - \sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}s^{n_{k}}\right) + f\!\left(\sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}s^{n_{k}}\right) \\
&= 1 - \sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}t^{n_{k}} + \sum\limits_{k} (-1)^{k}t^{n_{k}} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

As consequence we get that $f\!\left(2^{-1}\right) = 2^{-1}$.

> ### Claim 3
>
> There exists $\beta \in \left(0, 1\right)$ such that for $x \in \left(0, \beta\right)$
>   \begin{equation} f\!\left(x\right) < x \label{low x} \tag{10} \end{equation}

Assume that \eqref{low x} is not true. It means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $0 < x_{\varepsilon} < \varepsilon$ such that $f\!\left(x\right) \geqslant x$. But we have $f\!\left(s^{n}\right) = t^{n} < s^{n}$ for natural $n$ and $s^{n} \rightarrow 0$. Thus we can find a monotone sequence $x_{\varepsilon_{1}}, s^{n_{1}}, x_{\varepsilon_{2}}, s^{n_{2}}, \dots$ which converges to zero and for natural $k$ satisfies
\begin{align}
    f\!\left(x_{\varepsilon_{k}}\right) &\geqslant x_{\varepsilon_{k}} \\
    f\!\left(s^{n_{k}}\right) &< s^{n_{k}}
\end{align}

Applying Weierstrass theorem for every interval $\left[ s^{n_{k}}, x_{\varepsilon_{k}}\right]$ we find a monotone, converging to zero sequence $\left(y_{n}\right)$ of fixed points of $f$. Hence $f$ is strictly monotonous, difference $y_{n} - s^{n_{0}}$ has the same sign with $y_{n} - t^{n_{0}}$. To see this, for example, when $y_{n} < s^{n_{0}}$, just go to image of $f$. From here we can conclude that for $n \geqslant p$
\begin{equation}
    \left|\log_{s} y_{n} - \log_{t} y_{n}\right| \leqslant 1 \label{s, t ineq} \tag{11}
\end{equation}
where $p$ is selected so that $y_{p} < s$.
Indeed, for $m = \left\lfloor \log_{s} y_{n} \right\rfloor \in \mathbb{N}
$
\begin{equation}
    t^{m + 1} < s^{m + 1} < y_{n} < t^{m} < s^{m}
\end{equation}
which means that 
\begin{equation}
    m < \log_{s} y_{n}, \log_{t} y_{n} < m + 1
\end{equation}
and \eqref{s, t ineq} is true. Note that all inequalities a strict, because $s > k$ and $y_{n} = s^{k}$ for some $k$ implies $y_{n} = t^{k}$. Now rewrite \eqref{s, t ineq} in the next form
\begin{align}
    \left|1 - \dfrac{\log_{t} y_{n}}{\log_{s} y_{n}}\right| &\leqslant \dfrac{1}{\left|\log_{s} y_{n}\right|} \\
    \left|1 - \log_{t} s\right| &\leqslant \dfrac{1}{\left|\log_{s} y_{n}\right|}
\end{align}
Taking limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we come to the conclusion that $\log_{t} s = 1$ or $t = s$, which contradicts with initial condition.

---

Set of $\beta > 0$ such that on $\left(0, \beta\right)$  holds \eqref{low x} is nonempty and bounded: $b \leqslant 2^{-1}$ as $f\!\left(2^{-1}\right) = 2^{-1}$, so it's has a supremum $x_{0}$. From local properties of continuous functions, we have that
\begin{align}
    f\!\left(x\right) &< x,\quad x \in \left(0, x_{0}\right) \\
    f\!\left(x_{0}\right) &= x_{0}
\end{align}
and $x_{0} \leqslant 2^{-1} < s$. Now we find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such
\begin{equation}
    s^{n + 1} < x_{0} < s^{n}
\end{equation}
One more time, there are strict inequalities as $x_{0}$ is a fixed point, and points $s^{k}$, $k \geqslant 1$ are not. From **Claim 1** we have that for $x \in \left[0, s^{n+1}\right]$
\begin{align}
    f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1} + x\right) &= t^{n} - t^{n+1} + f\!\left(x\right) \\
    &= f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1}\right) + f\!\left(x\right) \\
    &< f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1}\right) + x
\end{align}
Now take $x = x_{0} + s^{n+1} - s^{n} \in \left[0, s^{n+1}\right]$ to have
\begin{align}
    f\!\left(x_{0}\right) &= x_{0} \\
    &< f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1}\right) + x_{0} + s^{n+1} - s^{n} \\
    s^{n} - s^{n+1} &< f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}
but $s^{n} - s^{n+1} = s^{n}\left(1 - s\right) < s^{n + 1}$, and we must have
\begin{equation}
    f\!\left(s^{n} - s^{n+1}\right) < s^{n} - s^{n+1} 
\end{equation}
by **Claim 3**. This contradiction completes the proof of nonexistence of such $f$.